# Code 406 when RESTlet client tries to get ArrayList of objects via @GET from JAX-RS service

Tags: rest, jax-rs, restlet

just started java development and tried to build an easy client-server application. I use JAX-RS for the server side and RESTlet for the client side.
I want to call the @GET method of the server side and get back a list of Customer objects

Here is some code:

server

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public ArrayList<Customer> showAllCustomers() {
    ArrayList<Customer> list = DBAccess.getInstance().getAllCustomers();
    return list;
}
```

client

```
package RESTlet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.restlet.resource.Delete;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Put;

import customer.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerResource {

@Get
public ArrayList<Customer> retrieve();

@Put
public void store(Customer contact);

@Delete
public void remove();
}
```

my try to receive the list in the main class

```
public class MainApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8080/CustomerRESTServicex/rest/customer");
    // Get the Contact object
    CustomerResource resource = cr.wrap(CustomerResource.class);
    ArrayList <Customer> customerList = resource.retrieve();
    for (Customer customer : customerList) {
        System.out.println(customer.getFirstname() + " " + customer.getLastname() + ", " + customer.getStreet() + " " + customer.getStreetnr());
    }
}
}
```

this is the exception i got

```
Exception in thread "main" Not Acceptable (406) - Not Acceptable
```

I`m looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: [HTTP 406](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) means that you are requesting something the server cannot fulfill. I'm not familiar with newer Restlet clients, but I would try putting a HTTP capturing proxy in the middle (something like Charles Proxy), so that way you can see the requests being generated by your code and the responses generated by the service as a starting point.

Comment: @Charlie thank you for your reply. I am aware of the meaning of code 406. The error code is just strange. I have a similar @GET method where i just request ONE object and not an ArrayList and it works... Just for the ArrayList there`s something wrong. I`ll try to put a proxy between, but perhaps im lucky and somebody already knows the answer. Thank you again Charlie